# Difference between apt-get compilation and manual compilation from source

Tags: libraries, compile, packages, make

I am trying to replace manually a library for freeradius.
On a one hand I installed freeradius with an apt-get install. There was a library "libfoo-2.0.4.so" (let's call it the lib(apt)).
On the other hand I used the sources (from apt-get source) to modify the library "libfoo-2.0.4.so" (let's call it the lib(src)). The i compiled the sources (./configure, make) to retrieve this modified lib(src). (The lib works fine when i test it).

When I try to manually replace lib(apt) by lib(src) the freeradius segfaults during the call of that library.
So it seems that the libraries are not compatible.

Could it be because of compilation issues? (precompiled version versus local compilation)
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if some build option in the package install is missing in the source-built version

Comment: Might be something like that, yes. Is there a way to know which build options were used for the precompiled version?

Comment: I have no clue, would be an interesting thing to ask though!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You should post your answer so i can mark it a the valid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that some build option that was used in the package install was missing in the source-built version you're using (assuming the changes to your code didn't cause it -this [SF question may be a good start troubleshooting that](https://serverfault.com/questions/61659/can-you-get-any-program-in-linux-to-print-a-stack-trace-if-it-segfaults)). Apparently you can use [auto-apt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#auto-apt) to pull in any dependancies as you're installing it but there's apparently no obvious tool to retrive what build options the original compilation used.